# How do I wrap text around an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website using html and CSS and I've been trying to find a way to put text on the same line as an image instead of just above and below it. It would be easier if the solution was in html because I know html a lot better than css

I tried alligning the text but it just stayed above and below the image. I tried to add more characters but same problem. It didn't wrap, it just made the page longer

Comment: May be you can try the float property in CSS. It will be a simple solution.

Comment: Do you know any solutions in html? All my CSS scripts are mostly copy and paste tbh I barely know any CSS

Comment: Can you share the code? It's hard to find a solution without knowing what's required.

Comment: https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/W21RTX1b5nnw this is the link. I'm using a site cuz my PC dead and all I have is my crappy laptop that can only run google and Microsoft paint

Comment: Are you trying to align the game logo and game name on the same line?

Comment: I'm trying to place the description on the right of the logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can use the CSS `shape-outside` Property to wrap the text with image.
The `shape-outside` Property comes with values ,

```
shape-outside: none |<shape-box&gt>  | <basic-shape> | <image> | initial | inherit
```

As the example for the above question:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  shape-outside: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/circle.png'); 
}

.img1{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14179/circle.png" alt="" class="img1"/>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel at commodi voluptates enim, distinctio officia. Saepe optio accusamus doloribus sint facilis itaque ab nulla, dolor molestiae assumenda cum sit placeat adipisci, libero quae nihil porro debitis laboriosam inventore animi impedit nostrum nesciunt quisquam expedita! Dolores consectetur iure atque a mollitia dicta repudiandae illum exercitationem aliquam repellendus ipsum porro modi, id nemo eligendi, architecto ratione quibusdam iusto nisi soluta? Totam inventore ea eum sed velit et eligendi suscipit accusamus iusto dolore, at provident eius alias maxime pariatur non deleniti ipsum sequi rem eveniet laboriosam magni expedita?
</p>
```